Implementing GPT-Like Structure for Generating Random Jokes in Power Virtual Agent Using Azure AI
I'm currently working on Power Virtual Agent and have a requirement to integrate a feature that generates random jokes, similar to the conversational style of GPT models. My initial plan is to leverage Azure AI services for this implementation. However, I'm unsure about the specific steps and techniques required to achieve this.
Could anyone provide guidance or ideas on how to proceed with integrating Azure AI to implement a GPT-like structure for generating jokes within Power Virtual Agent? Any insights, best practices, or recommended Azure services to use for this purpose would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!
Tried implementing GPT-like joke generation in Power Virtual Agent using Azure AI, expecting insights on Azure services and methods for achieving conversational joke generation within the platform.
